# Convert long to DateTime type

Tags: android, datetime

I want to save a `GregorianCalendar` data in the database. As far as I know, I can convert `GregorianCalendar` to `long` by method `getTimeInMillis` and save. But the problem is when retrieving data, I need the datatype `GregorianCalendar`. If possible, show me. Thnak

Comment: DateTime from jodatime?

Comment: Consider to use [`Calendar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)

Comment: @John Oh sorry, DateTime was defined by me, my fault. I use GregorianCalendar, any way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Try to convert from `Milliseconds` to `GregorianCalendar`. the search keyword you can try [`GregorianCalendar from TimeInMillis android`](https://www.google.com/search?q=GregorianCalendar&oq=GregorianCalendar&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=GregorianCalendar+from+TimeInMillis+android)

Comment: @John Tks, it's work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While retriving the data again convert the milliseconds to GregorianCalendar like below.

long timestamp = 123456789;

Calendar cal=GregorianCalendar.getInstance();

cal.setTime(timestamp);

Comment: long value will be the one which you already saved and retrieving again.

Comment: I got error: "The method setTime(Date) in type Calendar is not applicable for the arguments (long) "

Comment: use calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp)